# Python Image Ideal High/Low pass filter in frequency domain

Tags: python, image, dns, filtering, frequency

I need to implement a Image Low/High pass filer in frequency domain for educational purposes in college. 
The algorithm I'm applying is:

a) Perform the image centering transform on the original image
 
b) Perform the DFT transform
 
c) Alter the Fourier coefficients according to the required filtering
 
d) Perform the IDFT transform
 
e) Perform the image centering transform again (this undoes the first centering transform).

Here is my code so far

```
import struct
import numpy as np
from math import pow
from cmath import exp, pi

imIn = open("before.bmp", "rb")

#Get informations from .bmp file section#
print 'Identifier: ', imIn.read(2)  
print 'File size: ', struct.unpack('i',imIn.read(4))[0]
print 'Reserved: ', struct.unpack('i', imIn.read(4))[0]
offset = struct.unpack('i', imIn.read(4))[0]
print 'Data offset: ',offset
print 'Header size: ',struct.unpack('i', imIn.read(4))[0]
width = struct.unpack('i', imIn.read(4))[0]
print 'Width: ',width
height = struct.unpack('i', imIn.read(4))[0]
print 'Height: ',height
#-------------------------------------------#


#back to zero and write header section which is copied from the original file
imIn.seek(0)
header = imIn.read(offset)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#


# build data array
imArr = []
count = 0
for i in range(0,width):
    row = []
    for j in range(0,height):
        tmp = imIn.read(1)
        val = struct.unpack('c', tmp)[0]
        row.append(val)
    imArr.append(row)
#------------------#


# write header information
imOut = open("after.bmp","wb")
imOut.write(header)
#-------------------------#
ArrInt =[]

for i in range(0,width):
    row = []
    for j in range(0,height):
        row.append(ord(imArr[i][j]))
    ArrInt.append(row)
del(imArr)

#center image
for i in range(0,width):
    row = []
    for j in range(0,height):
        ArrInt[i][j] = pow((-1),i*j)*ArrInt[i][j]
 #--------------------------------

#fourier transformation
iArr =  np.fft.fft2(ArrInt)
#---------------------------------------

#filer aplication(low pass filter)
R = 1000 #distance
for i in range(0,width):
    for j in range(0,height):
        temp = pow(float(height)/float(2)-i,2) + pow(float(width)/float(2)-j,2)
        if temp > pow(R,2):
            iArr[i][j] = 0
        elif temp <= pow(R,2):
            iArr[i][j] = iArr[i][j].real
#-----------------------------------

#fourier inverse transformation
iArr =  np.fft.ifft2(iArr)
#------------------------------

#center image
for i in range(0,width):
    row = []
    for j in range(0,height):
        iArr[i][j] = pow((-1),i*j)*iArr[i][j]
#---------------------------------------

for i in range(0,width):
    for j in range(0,height):
        if int(iArr[i][j].real) > 255:
            imOut.write(struct.pack('c',chr(int(255))))
        elif int(iArr[i][j].real) < 0:
            imOut.write(struct.pack('c',chr(int(0))))
        else: imOut.write(struct.pack('c',chr(int(iArr[i][j].real))))

#Close files section#
imIn.close()
imOut.close()
#-------------------#
```

My problem is: I don't get the expected result and I can't figure out what I did wrong.
These are my input and output images:
[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3v4z.png)
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZYvA.png)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with your core problem, but you can get rid of that weird overlap by eliminating the `elif temp <= pow(R,2):  iArr[i][j] = iArr[i][j].real`. You won't see any filtering with that radius, try something smaller, eg 64.0. I don't understand your centering algorithm, but numpy has centering & de-centering functions `np.fft.fftshift` and `np.fft.ifftshift`, but you should call them on the frequency-domain data, i.e., call `np.fft.fftshift` after `np.fft.fft2`.

Comment: BTW, you appear to have horizontal & vertical reversed: a 2D array of your image consists of an array of rows, so `ArrInt[i][j]` refers to the pixel in the j'th row of the i'th column. FWIW, there are several things you can change to make your code more efficient. Eg, you shouldn't read the image data pixel by pixel. `struct.unpack('c', x)[0]` returns byte `x` unchanged. The `**` operator is faster than calling the `pow` function.

Comment: I should also mention that the sharp cutoff in your low-pass filter will introduce [ringing artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts).

Comment: Also, it's hard to test your BMP-oriented code with that PNG image, and decoding / encoding BMP images by hand is a bit fragile, it's better to use a library (eg PIL/Pillow) to handle reading & writing image data, but even that's not guaranteed to work correctly with all BMP formats. :) OTOH, PIL has some support for Numpy arrays. If you _do_ decide to use PIL, it's a Good Idea to do an `Image.convert('L')` step on the input image before further processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PM 2Ring. It seems that my image was converted into PNG, [Here](http://file-share.top/file/32480/before-zip) I hosted the image in .zip file. I will use your suggestions and come back.

Comment: I modified my script and started using PIL library. The cutoff in the frequency domain is too sharp and that produces ringing artifacts. Next I will implement Gaussian filter, this should provide a smoother cutoff. Thanks again for your answer, it was very helful.